# LibGDX ClassNotFound on Android

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, gradle, libgdx

I'm using libGDX for my game which shares some code with another project. I put this code in a .jar library which I have added in the root build.gradle.

Everything works fine on desktop, but when I launch the game on Android it crashes with a ClassNotFound exception. It can't find a class of my the library.

Can anyone help me out? I have no idea what is causing the problem.

Edit: changes to build.gradle:

```
project(":core") {
    apply plugin: "java"


    dependencies {
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype:$gdxVersion"
        compile fileTree(dir: '../libs', include: '*.jar')
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show the changes you made to the root `build.gradle`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the same `fileTree` dependency directly in the `android` module because the Android Gradle plugin currently can't handle transitive flat file dependencies.

```
project(":core") {
   ...
   compile fileTree(dir: '../libs', include: '*.jar')
   ...
}

// And also

project(":android") {
   ...
   compile fileTree(dir: '../libs', include: '*.jar')
   ...
}
```

[Source](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Dependency-management-with-Gradle#android-pitfall).